# Kendo UI MVC -- how do you get a more flexable grid custom command?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to overcome the limitations of the custom command binding for a Kendo MVC grid? I was somewhat stuck in that the custom command only provides for a static label and a button but what I wanted was an HTML link and some part of the existing model to show up as the display part of the link.

Documentation clearly states that this is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solution for version 2013.1.319.

here is the answer that I got: ** Credit to Telerik support **

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
   .Name("grid")  
    .Columns(columns =>  
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);  
        columns.Template(t => { }).ClientTemplate("<a href='\\#' onclick='displayItem(\"#= data.uid #\")'>Display #= data.ProductName # </a> ");
    })
   ...
)
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function displayItem(uid) {  
        var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);
        console.log(dataItem);
}
</script>
```